# WebWorks BB7 Packager Ignoring Files

Tags: blackberry-webworks

Blackberry WebWorks Packager has functionality to ignore some resources when packaging the application from a directory.

This functionality is documented as [Exclude files using the .bbwpignore file](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/using_bbwpignore_file.html#bpa1351179633058).

I can't seem to find any similar functionality for packaging an application on BB7 and `.bbwpignore` file doesn't work.  Is this functionality limited to BB10?  Does anyone have any other suggestions other than creating some sort of ignore script and then packaging a zip.

Answer (score 0):

There is no .bbwpignore file for the BBOS WebWorks Packager. As you have written, the only option is not to include the files in the zip.